# Tikz subfigures overlap

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption

I tried to search on the internet but I had no luck.

I did 2 figures in TikZ and I wanted to put them side by side through the `subcaption` package.

This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference,tikz]{memoir}  % Comment this line out 
\usepackage{subcaption}
%TikZ 
\usepackage{tikz}
% Begin document
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    %\draw[dashed](0,0)--(2,2);
    %\draw (0,0) grid (10,10);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% NODES
    %\draw [red,line width=1,fill=black] (0,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (0,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (0,1) {$\mathbf{1}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (2,1) {$\mathbf{2}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,3) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (2,3) {$\mathbf{3}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (5,1) {$\mathbf{4}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,3) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (5,3) {$\mathbf{5}$};
    %\draw [line width =1.3,->] (0.12,1.28) to (0.82,2.74);
    %\draw [line width =1.3,<->] (0.3,1) to (1.7,1);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% EDGES
    \draw [line width =1.3] (0.3,1) to (1.7,1);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2,2.8) to (2,1.2);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,1) to (4.8,1);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (5,1.2) to (5,2.8);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,3) to (4.8,3);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
           \caption{Subfigure A}
            \label{fig:subfig8}
        \end{subfigure}  
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    %\draw[dashed](0,0)--(2,2);
    %\draw (0,0) grid (10,10);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% NODES
    %\draw [red,line width=1,fill=black] (0,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (0,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (0,1) {$\mathbf{1}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (2,1) {$\mathbf{2}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,3) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (2,3) {$\mathbf{3}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (5,1) {$\mathbf{4}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,3) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (5,3) {$\mathbf{5}$};
    %\draw [line width =1.3,->] (0.12,1.28) to (0.82,2.74);
    %\draw [line width =1.3,<->] (0.3,1) to (1.7,1);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% EDGES
    %\draw [line width =1.3] (0.3,1) to (1.7,1);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2,2.8) to (2,1.2);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,1) to (4.8,1);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (5,1.2) to (5,2.8);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,3) to (4.8,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
            \caption{Subfigure B}
            \label{fig:subfig10}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ciao} 
    \label{fig:subfig1.a.4}
    \end{figure}   
\end{document}
```

but they overlap. Could you help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: just put `\hfill` between `subfigures` ...

Comment: I tried that but then the figures go out of the column width

Comment: this is not possible, the are only pushed to text border ... please add more information to your question (from your mwe follows, that you have only one column and in this case you have enough place for your images)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

as i said in comment, sub figures will push (maximal) apart `\hfill` between them. even better is use:

```
\begin{figure}{...}
\centering    % <--- added
\begin{subfigure}
...
\end{subfigure}{...}
\hfil       % <--- added
\begin{subfigure}
...
\end{subfigure}
...
\end{figure}
```

complete mwe (i take a liberty in rewrite your image code):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{memoir} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
%TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Begin document
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering  % <--- for centering sub figures on page
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 10mm and 10mm, %  <--- control distances between nodes
C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=black, 
            font=\bfseries, text=white}
                        ]
%% NODES
\node (n1)  [C] {1};
\node (n2)  [C,right=of n1] {2};
\node (n4)  [C,right=of n2] {4};
\node (n3)  [C,above=of n2] {3};
\node (n5)  [C,above=of n4] {5};
%% EDGES
\draw [line width =1.3pt]   
    (n1) to (n2)    
    (n2) to (n3)    (n2) to (n4)    (n3) to (n5)    (n5) to (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Subfigure A}
    \label{fig:subfig8}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil  % <--- push sub figures appart
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 10mm and 10mm, %  <--- control distances between nodes
C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=black,
            font=\bfseries, text=white}
                        ]
%% NODES
\node (n1)  [C] {1};
\node (n2)  [C,right=of n1] {2};
\node (n4)  [C,right=of n2] {4};
\node (n3)  [C,above=of n2] {3};
\node (n5)  [C,above=of n4] {5};
%% EDGES
\draw [line width =1.3pt]
    (n2) to (n3)    (n2) to (n4)    (n3) to (n5)    (n5) to (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Subfigure B}
    \label{fig:subfig10}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{ciao}
    \label{fig:subfig1.a.4}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

use \subfig package

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference,tikz]{memoir}  % Comment this line out 
% \usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}

% Begin document
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \subfloat[subfigure A]{  \label{fig:subfig8}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (0,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (0,1) {$\mathbf{1}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (2,1) {$\mathbf{2}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,3) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (2,3) {$\mathbf{3}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (5,1) {$\mathbf{4}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,3) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (5,3) {$\mathbf{5}$};

    \draw [line width =1.3] (0.3,1) to (1.7,1);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2,2.8) to (2,1.2);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,1) to (4.8,1);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (5,1.2) to (5,2.8);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,3) to (4.8,3);
    \end{tikzpicture} 

    }  \hfill
    \subfloat[subfigure B]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (0,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (0,1) {$\mathbf{1}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (2,1) {$\mathbf{2}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,3) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (2,3) {$\mathbf{3}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,1) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (5,1) {$\mathbf{4}$};
    \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,3) circle [radius=0.3];
    \node [white] at (5,3) {$\mathbf{5}$};

    \draw [line width =1.3] (2,2.8) to (2,1.2);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,1) to (4.8,1);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (5,1.2) to (5,2.8);
    \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,3) to (4.8,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
            \label{fig:subfig10}
}
    \caption{ciao} 
    \label{fig:subfig1.a.4}
    \end{figure}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: They told me that subfig is deprecated :( and I went for subcaption

Comment: they told you correct. `subcaption` has some advantages over `subfig`, (using `hyperref`). and changing sub images environment doesn't solve your problem. use of `hfil` solve it.

Comment: subfigure is deprecated, not subfig (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\subcaptionbox` instead environment `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference,tikz]{memoir}  % Comment this line out 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{Subfigure A\label{fig:subfig8}}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (0,1) circle [radius=0.3];
        \node [white] at (0,1) {$\mathbf{1}$};
        \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,1) circle [radius=0.3];
        \node [white] at (2,1) {$\mathbf{2}$};
        \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,3) circle [radius=0.3];
        \node [white] at (2,3) {$\mathbf{3}$};
        \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,1) circle [radius=0.3];
        \node [white] at (5,1) {$\mathbf{4}$};
        \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,3) circle [radius=0.3];
        \node [white] at (5,3) {$\mathbf{5}$};
        \draw [line width =1.3] (0.3,1) to (1.7,1);
        \draw [line width =1.3] (2,2.8) to (2,1.2);
        \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,1) to (4.8,1);
        \draw [line width =1.3] (5,1.2) to (5,2.8);
        \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,3) to (4.8,3);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
    \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{Subfigure B\label{fig:subfig10}}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (0,1) circle [radius=0.3];
        \node [white] at (0,1) {$\mathbf{1}$};
        \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,1) circle [radius=0.3];
        \node [white] at (2,1) {$\mathbf{2}$};
        \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (2,3) circle [radius=0.3];
        \node [white] at (2,3) {$\mathbf{3}$};
        \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,1) circle [radius=0.3];
        \node [white] at (5,1) {$\mathbf{4}$};
        \draw [line width=1,fill=black] (5,3) circle [radius=0.3];
        \node [white] at (5,3) {$\mathbf{5}$};
        \draw [line width =1.3] (2,2.8) to (2,1.2);
        \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,1) to (4.8,1);
        \draw [line width =1.3] (5,1.2) to (5,2.8);
        \draw [line width =1.3] (2.2,3) to (4.8,3);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }   
    \caption{ciao} 
    \label{fig:subfig1.a.4}
    \end{figure}   
\end{document}
```

[image]